# Trying to use Outlook paths in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-onenote-2010

I want to create a link in One Note that would go to relevant folder in Outlook.

I've created an Outlook path using this guide [Create Hyperlinks to Outlook Messages, Folders, Contacts and Events](https://www.davidtan.org/create-hyperlinks-to-outlook-messages-folders-contacts-events/)

But when I click on the link (after the security warning) I get the modal popup

> You'll need a new app to open this outlook

with only option being:

> Look for an app in the Store

.

I cannot event browse for program/app locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Outlook 2007, outlook:// protocol is not registered by default. You'll need to register it manually. Here is the .reg file for Outlook 2010:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook]
@="URL:Outlook Folders"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\OUTLOOK.EXE\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\shell\open]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\OUTLOOK.EXE\" /select \"%1\""
```

Comment: Works like a charm!